# Is there any way to get all the media with information by one API request Instagram Graph API?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Facebook recently changes its Instagram API. Now I can get all the `media` ids by requesting from this endpoint-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/{ig-user-id}/media?access_token=...
```

But it only returns the media Ids, not any other media information such as `caption`, `media_url`, `comments_count`, `likes_count` etc.

For getting these data, I have to request from the API-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/{ig-media-id}?fields=caption,media_url,comments_count&access_token=...
```

This is working well but the problem is I have to hit this API for each and every `{ig-media-id}` which is not a good thing.

So, is there any way to get all the media with information (`caption`, `media_url`, `comments_count`, `likes_count`) by one API request like-

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/{ig-user-id}/media?fields=caption,media_url&access_token=...
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#field-expansion, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for your comment. You may misunderstand me. The first endpoint at my question returns the media but it only returns the `ids`. For getting the detail of a media I have to hit the 2nd endpoint. And suppose I am trying to get 8 media and for that I have to hit the 2nd API 8 times. So my question is how could I get the media with details by one API hit.

Comment: No, I did not misunderstand you.

Comment: @CBroe could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem using **[Nested Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion)**. Special thanks to @Cbroe.

I've gained the result by using one query after changing the 1st API like this-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/{ig-user-id}?fields=media.limit(4){id,caption,media_url}&access_token=...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.instagram.com/<version(optional)>/me/media?fields=<fields-to-be-retrieved>&access_token=<your-access-token>&limit=<limit-number-of-responses(optional)>
```

> the above endpoint (replace placeholders with actual values) gets all the
> media associated with a user (you have to use paging for large data
> set), you can generate long-lived access token from access token
> generator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).